# Go get via a socks5h proxy

Tags: go, devops

I have an isolated DNS testbed where all tools that need the internet go through a SOCKS5 proxy and use it to resolve DNS (SOCKS5h). `git`, `apt` and `curl` don't have an issues; `go` does. Even when setting `http_proxy=socks5h://user1:pass1@192.168.0.1:8100 go mod tidy` go does not use the proxy to resolve DNS so I get a lookup error.

So is there any way to solve this? I am willing to add another proxy type, I just really need to keep Layer 3 isolated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to issue [#24135](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24135) and [#13454](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13454), `net/http` package in the Go standard library does not currently support `socks5h://`. Only `socks5://` is currently supported.